# VMWare Guest Info - Wrong IP Returned

Tags: vmware-vsphere

We're running a VDI environment with vSphere 4.0 and Oracle VDI 3.2.2 and are having a bit of a problem with users that connect to an IPSec VPN from within their VM. For some reason, once connected to the VPN, the VMWare API returns GuestInfo.ipAddress as the VPN IP rather than the primary IP of the only NIC on the system. The IP address shown in net[0].ipAddress is the correct address and is what vSphere client is reporting.

Is there any way to get VMWare tools to report the net[0].ipAddress as GuestInfo.ipAddress?

Below is sample output from the guestinfo.pl script. 172.16.1.2 is the example "bad" VPN address that our VDI software is seeing.

```
VMXFLEX01 guestFamily: windowsGuest
VMXFLEX01 guestFullName: Microsoft Windows XP Professional (32-bit)
VMXFLEX01 guestId: winXPProGuest
VMXFLEX01 guestState: running
VMXFLEX01 hostName: VMXFLEX01
VMXFLEX01 ipAddress: 172.16.1.2
VMXFLEX01 toolsStatus: VMware Tools is running and the version is current.
VMXFLEX01 toolsVersion: 8194
VMXFLEX01 Screen - Height: 600
VMXFLEX01 Screen - Width: 800
VMXFLEX01 Disk[0]: Capacity 42935926784
VMXFLEX01 Disk[0]: Path : C:\
VMXFLEX01 Disk[0]: freespace : 33272619008
VMXFLEX01 net[0] - connected : 1
VMXFLEX01 net[0] - deviceConfigId : 4000
VMXFLEX01 net[0] - macAddress : 00:50:56:95:1f:c9
VMXFLEX01 net[0] - network : VM Network
VMXFLEX01 net[0] - ipAddress : 10.0.0.2
```